# LinQ query - Cannot use Date as its non-primitive EDM type. Also cannot convert DateTime to String

Tags: c#, linq

I have below linQ Query for which I am getting the error:
*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

```
var query =   from i in Expenditure
              join d in Department on i.DepartId equals d.dID
              where i.Status == "Audit"
              group i by new { i.InvoiceId, d.Title, i.InvoiceDate } into g
              select new
              {
                id = g.Key.InvoiceId,
                txt = g.Key.Title + " // " + g.Key.InvoiceId + " // " + Convert.ToString(g.Key.InvoiceDate)
              };
```

I want txt output as follow:

Health // Inv001 // 12-03-2018
Education // Inv002 // 23-03-3018

Problem is with InvoiceDate (Datetime) field for which I initially wrote (without the Convert)as:   g.Key.InvoiceDate
but I got error as: *Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*

Can anyone suggest an easy solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToString isn't an SQL function, therefore it can't be done within the SQL query.

Try this:

```
var query =   (from i in Expenditure
              join d in Department on i.DepartId equals d.dID
              where i.Status == "Audit"
              group i by new { i.InvoiceId, d.Title, i.InvoiceDate } into g
              select new
              {
                g.Key.InvoiceId,
                g.Key.Title,
                g.Key.InvoiceDate,
              }).ToList()
              .select new
              {
                id = InvoiceId,
                txt = Title + " // " + InvoiceId + " // " + Convert.ToString(InvoiceDate)
              };
```

Everything after the .ToList() will be done in memory, where you can use any .NET method.

Comment: copy paste other answers isn't a good practice. besides that code don't even compile.

Comment: @tchelidze I copied the question, not an answer. Assuming the code in the question compiles, this should too.

Comment: Looks like it's clone of my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, when I started answering your answer wasn't there. Now that I look at it, it doesn't seem to work - the convert to string is still before the .ToList()

Comment: No worries, just wanted to note

Comment: Note the spacing in my answer matches the question, not the spacing in your answer.

Comment: Right, i mean that ideas behind our answers are the same, not the code itself.

Comment: Well, that is the logical approach. Using `SqlFunctions` would be an overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assembling `txt` in database and force `Linq To Entities` to transform your logic into SQL, first retrieve the data and then apply transformations

Try following

```
var query =   
         (from i in Expenditure
          join d in Department on i.DepartId equals d.dID
          where i.Status == "Audit"
          group i by new { i.InvoiceId, d.Title, i.InvoiceDate } into g
          select new
          {
            id = g.Key.InvoiceId,
            title = g.Key.Title,
            invoiceId = g.Key.InvoiceId,
            invoiceDate =  g.Key.InvoiceDate
          })
          .ToList()
          .Select(it => new 
            { 
               id = it.id, 
               txt = it.title + " // " + it.invoiceId + " // " + it.invoiceDate 
            });
```

Comment: thanks for consideration but its still giving error:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Removing Convert did the job as shown in Danny solution. But credit to both